# when i run php artisan migrate, i encounter an error

Tags: laravel

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `personal_a ccess_tokens` add index `personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index`(`tokenable_

I tried to add index with the specified key length

```
$table->index(['tokenable_type', 'tokenable_id'], 'tokenable_index');
```

but still encountering the error

Answer (score 0):

You can try shorten column name like this

```
$table->index(['type', 'tokenable_id'], 'tokenable_index');
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who tried modifying the AppServiceProvider

`public function boot() { Schema::defaultStringLength(191); }`

and still get the same error, try changing MySQL engine in config/database.php to 'InnoDB'.